# how to access the class properties based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection, properties

I have below the object and its internal objects and I have added custom attributes to the property names which are required for the report.

```
public class Space
{
    public SpaceIdentity SpaceIdentity { get; set; } = new();
    public SpaceGeometry SpaceGeometry { get; set; } = new();
    public AirBalance AirBalance { get; set; } = new();
    public EngineeringChecks EngineeringChecks { get; set; } = new();
}
public class SpaceIdentity
{
    public int ElementId { get; set; } // Not required
    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Space Number", IsIncludedInReport2 = true)]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Space Name", IsIncludedInReport2 = true, IsIncludedInReport1 = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Room Number", IsIncludedInReport1 = true)]
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Room Name", IsIncludedInReport1 = true)]
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
}

public class SpaceGeometry
{
    public Vertex LocationPoint { get; set; } // this is not required
    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Space Area", Units = "(ft²)", IsIncludedInReport1 = true)]
    public double FloorArea { get; set; }
}
.....
```

Here I am building an excel report, which I want to use property display name's as header column names of that report. Here are some of the properties attribute information used in multiple reports. What I did was I added a bool condition attribute like (`isIncludedInReport1`) and loop through the properties of `space` and loop through the properties of inner object(`SpaceGeometry`) to get a particular property name and its attribute values based on this boolean condition.

What I am looking for here is without adding these bool attributes, is there any way to access the property names based on condition. I thought about adding interfaces, but that is not possible here because I have multiple inner classes having properties that I need to include in a single report.

Could anyone please let me know is there any other way to achieve this?

Update:

```
   var columnResult = new OrderedDictionary();
    GetReportHeaderColumnName(typeof(Space), columnResult);
    
    public static void GetReportHeaderColumnName(Type type, OrderedDictionary headerNameByUnit)
    {
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass && !propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System."))
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Overridable<double>))
                {
                    AddReportHeaderName(headerNameByUnit, propertyInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    GetReportHeaderColumnName(propertyInfo.PropertyType, headerNameByUnit);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AddReportHeaderName(headerNameByUnit, propertyInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    protected static void AddReportHeaderName(OrderedDictionary columnResult, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameWithUnitsAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            var displayNameWithUnitsAttribute = (DisplayNameWithUnitsAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof(DisplayNameWithUnitsAttribute));

            if (displayNameWithUnitsAttribute.IsIncludedInReport2)
            {
                columnResult.Add(displayNameWithUnitsAttribute.DisplayName, displayNameWithUnitsAttribute.Units);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far, and what is the problem. It is easy to add any attributes, but what are you going to do after this? do you really need them?

Comment: I do not want to use those boolean attributes to access the property names and at the moment I am using those.

Comment: @Serge, I updated my question

Comment: @Serge, I am looking for a solution or suggestion on not using that bool attributes and getting the property names for individual reports.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking us how you can specify which columns to include in the report without using attributes. Is that right? If that is the case, we need to understand the use case. Who is in charge of deciding whether a column is included in the report? How would they *like* to express their preference?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. They don't like to use the boolean attributes to define which is included in which report. As I mentioned, I have an idea of all the properties and I have included them as attributes(IsIncludedInReport1) on property names. So is there any way to achieve the same with out using the bool type attributes

Comment: @JohnWu,  I still want these attributes (display Name, Units) to be with property names and looking a way to get rid of only that boolean attribute.

Comment: @EnigmaState The problem here is that you insist on specifying the requirement by stating what the system should *not* do. Requirements are best specified by stating what the system *should* do. For example, maybe you would like it if the end user could specify the column names by typing them into a cell in an Excel workbook. Or maybe you require them to be configurable only by a developer. You need to narrow it down. Saying it should not use attributes tells us very little. There's probably a hundred ways to do it.

Comment: @JohnWu, Sorry for the confusion. At the moment, I have added the display name attribute and unit attribute to the property names, which I am going to include in the reports. In some classes, only a few property display names need to be in the report, and in some classes, few of the properties display names common in one-two report.

Comment: At the moment, I have added a boolean attribute to identify which properties need to be included in which report, along with the display attribute. Now I want to remove only the boolean attribute and look for an elegant way to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that doesn't use reflection is to just use a list of `ReportProperty`

```cs
public record ReportProperty<T>(
    Func<T, string> ValueFunc,
    string DisplayName,
    string? Unit = null
    );

List<ReportProperty<Space>> report1 = new(){
    new( s => s.SpaceIdentity.Number, "Space Number"),
    new( s => s.SpaceIdentity.RoomNumber, "Room Number"),
    new( s => s.SpaceIdentity.RoomName, "Room Name"),
    new( s => s.SpaceGeometry.FloorArea.ToString(), "Floor Area", "Ft2"),
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I still need to use the reflection to get display name attributes and units, but I don't want to use the boolean attributes. I am thinking of making an interface and casting that interface to get the property info. The interface is a combination of so many properties, and that is where I am stepping back. I do not want to hardcode names because more than 70 columns are there in one report.

Comment: If you don't want the property names as attributes in the code where do you want it? Should it be coded somewhere else? Should it be loaded from a text file at runtime? From a database?

Comment: I am keeping display names with property names in a single place so that if there is any change, it will be a single place. If I have to hardcode property names in another place, then it will be critical to track.

Comment: You are not answering the question. Where *do* you want the property names? You have to have a list of them somewhere. Does that need to be a text file, or should it be inside a list in c# code?

Comment: Do you mean desired property names for each report? I put these models in another c# library and consumed those in the main API. If I put attributes like bool, this makes the shared library too dependent on one of its consumers(API). At the same time, I do not want to write desired property names in a separate list and compare them with actual property names.

Comment: I understand what you *don't* want, you have said that 10 times by now. You must have some idea what you *do* want. Give us an example of something you have tried or thought about. Nobody is going to list all 700 possible solutions for you.

Comment: I am not asking 700 possible solutions, I tried your solutions before, and in the end, I implemented what I mentioned in the question, but thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve by making it another way? I assume you want to make your code scalable so adding more reports is easier.

Do you still want to use attributes on the classes themselves? If so, you could make a new attribute, and tag your properties like so:

```
public class SpaceIdentity
{
    public int ElementId { get; set; } // Not required
    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Space Number")]
    [IncludeInReport(2)]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    
    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Space Name")]
    [IncludeInReport(1)]
    [IncludeInReport(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Room Number")]
    [IncludeInReport(1)]
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayNameWithUnits(DisplayName = "Room Name")]
    [IncludeInReport(1)]
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
}
```

Or do you want to separate the report from the classes, so your report is defined in another file? If so, maybe a 2-dimensional list of property names would do the trick:

```
List<List<string>> Report1 = new()
{
    new(){nameof(Space.SpaceIdentity), nameof(SpaceIdentity.Name)},
    new(){nameof(Space.SpaceIdentity), nameof(SpaceIdentity.RoomNumber)},
    new(){nameof(Space.SpaceIdentity), nameof(SpaceIdentity.RoomName)},
    new(){nameof(Space.SpaceGeometry), nameof(SpaceGeometry.FloorArea)}
};
```

Comment: I do not want to use boolean attributes to identify which is included in the report and do not want to hard code header names. Later it will be more cumbersome. I am looking for any other way to achieve the same.